# Bluecove for osx 10.10

Tags: java, bluetooth, osx-yosemite, bluecove

I wanted to use bluecove(2.1.1 snapshot) in my mac with OSX 10.10 and the driver doesn't work.

I got  libbluecove.jnilib: mach-o, but wrong architecture

I tried to recompile but the available code it too old (from 2010) and there are a lot or change that doesn't apply.

Is there a way to make it work ? or is there another java API to interact with bluetooth ?

Thanks